# Could you tell me whether you like dogs or cats? - Questions and Intonation: Up or Down?

Tags: pronunciation, intonation

https://rachelsenglish.com/questions-intonation/

According to this video, yes-no questions have an intonation that goes up at the end.

Other types have an intonation that goes down.

But if it is a mixed type of question, what should we do?

**Example 1**

> Could you tell me whether you like dogs or cats?

Should the intonation at the end of the sentence go down or go up?

**Example 2**

> Could you tell me whether you like dogs, rabbits, or cats?

Should the intonation at the end of the sentence go down or go up?

**Example 3**

> Could you tell me whether you have stolen things before?

Should the intonation at the end of the sentence go down or go up?

**Example 4**

> Could you tell me whether you have stolen things before or not?

Should the intonation at the end of the sentence go down or go up?

Answer (score 2):

As a British English speaker, I'm not sure that I would always use the same intonations as Rachel does. However, I think the dogs/cats one depends on whether you are asking the other person to choose one.

> Would you like some tea or coffee? (Up - offering a hot drink.)
>
> Would you like *tea* or *coffee?* (emphasising both words, down at end - asking them to choose.)

(3) and (4) seem to me to be expecting a yes/no answer to start with.

Comment: It's the same in American English. Up at the end: do you like any of the listed choices? Down at the end: which one would you prefer? But example four requires choosing one of two mutually exclusive options, so the intonation should  fall at the end.

Answer (score 0):

1. Up/Down - both acceptable
2. Down
3. Up
4. Down

Tip: try saying it out loud and see which suits best! I do not think there is one way to define whether a question should have an up or down intonation, it is usually a matter of preference and how it sounds.